# How to change text from specific cells in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I made a mistake in a dataframe I uploaded. In the image below I want to change the "MB" in the two cells outlined in red to "BT"

[My dataframe in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxU59.png)

I already tried the `assign`  function, but I just want to change the text from these two cell to different text, not give values to names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
foo[[6]][[50]] <- "BT"
foo[[6]][[51]] <- "BT"
```

where `foo` is the name of your data frame (your screenshot doesn't show that). Regardless of name values, you can always address individual cells in a data frame with the `[[column]][[row]]` syntax.